# How access data in JavaScript arrays using $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is a script when the script is executed I want to load the data into  the div of id `#trial`. The script is an external array with three names the second I am trying to call is 'sarah'. Whats wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#trial").click(function(){
        var attempt=$.ajax({
            url: "names.js",
            dataType: "script"
        });
        var msg=names[1];
        attempt.done(function( msg ) {
            $( "#trial" ).html( msg );
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#trial").click(function(){

           $.ajax({
                 url: "names.js",
                 dataType: "script",
                 success: function(res){
                      //todo something with res
                 }
           });
       });
   });
</script>
```